# Most scalable typescript module organization with the least amount of overhead?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a file structure as follows

```
controllers
  index.ts
  user.ts
  topic.ts
models
  index.ts
  user.ts
  topic.ts
```

Each of the `index.ts` files are for consolidating the exported entities within the directory. The other files contain a single export of the same name.

The cognitive model which makes most intuitive sense to me would be to access the user model from some other file by doing

```
///someExternalModule.ts (method 1)

import models from '../models';

models.user.method();
```

Therefore maintaining a `models/index.ts` which looks like

```
///models/index.ts  (method 1)

import {user} from '../user';

const models = {
  user
};

export default models;
```

However, what I usually see in other code bases is a suffix attached to every model/controller.

```
///someExternalModule.ts (method 2)

import {userModel} from '../models'
```

With syntactic sugar in the index:

```
///models/index.ts  (method 2)
export {userModel} from './user'
```

I know this is a somewhat up-to-taste question, but I feel that there must be some objective pros/cons to either. For example, is there an overhead to importing the entire models directory every time we want to access one of the models?

Furthermore, is there a more elegant way to maintain either of these kinds of `index.ts`? It seems like something that should be automated by now-- I assume 80% of projects just want to proxy the export of each entity exported by a file in the directory. This kind of organization seems like it should be a use case of the typescript `module` keyword to combine entities from across files into the same module, but I can't find any literature supporting that.

Comment: Your first examples don't match. For `export const models = ` to work, you'd have to do `import { models } from '../models';`. There's little reason to have a named export called "models" from a module that is already called that, when you can make the named export `user` instead.

Comment: Ah! Good catch; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

IMO avoid using default exports. Using named export would be more preferred.

And you can do this instead:

```
// index.ts
export * from './a'
export * from './b'
```

You don't need to specify the content, making the whole thing transparent.

Default export was meant to provide something similar to `exports = x` in CommonJS, but it has several drawbacks.

Comment: Hm... `import __ = require('__')` syntax is used at several places in my code base. What are the drawbacks?

Comment: That is commonjs syntax which is fine. I refer to the default export in es6 `import x from './y'`